# Jest - ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined (React Native)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, jestjs

I am trying to get jest to work with a new `react-native` project. However, when I run `npm run test`, I get the following error `ReferenceError: __DEV__ is not defined`. I've looked through countless Github issues and Stack Overflow posts regarding this but none of the suggestions have worked in my case.

Here is my `jest.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
    transformIgnorePatterns: [
       "node_modules/(?!(react-native|react-native-button|react-native-video)/)"
    ],  
    setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/__tests__/setup.json'],  
}
```

`package.json` (notice I added **DEV** = true inside "jest")

```
{
  "name": "DigitalSignagePlayer",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.2",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.14.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.2",
    "eslint": "^7.28.0",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
  }

}
```

`bable.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset', '@babel/preset-env'],
  
};
```

`metro.config.js`

```
/**
 * Metro configuration for React Native
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: true,
      },
    }),
  },
};
```

I have tried setting `globals.DEV = true` and `global.DEV = true` at the top of my test files. I have tried adding `setupFiles` to `jest.config.js` which loads a `setup.js` file that contains `global.DEV = true` too. I have tried updating `jest` also. My current version of `react-native` is:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.64.2
```

I'm also using Metro, not Expo and I initially created the app with react-native-cli.

UPDATE:

`setup.json`

```
{
    "globals": { "__DEV__": true } 
}
```

UPDATE 2:

I changed `setup.json` to `setup.js` but I am still getting the same error:

```
 global.__DEV__ = true
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable is called `__DEV__`, so using `DEV` by trial and error doesn't make sense. Setting it in tests won't help because it won't affect the usage of the variable on import. In order to do this, this should have been done before tests in `setupFiles*` files.

Jes `globals` configuration option is supposed to do this. There should be `"globals": { "__DEV__": true }`. The configuration in package.json overridden by the configuration in jest.config.js. There should be only one of them (likely the latter), the other one needs to be removed.

Comment: I wasn't able to get your suggestion to work. I have updated the question to reflect my changes.

Comment: 'globals' should be located in jest.config.js, check https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration . setupFiles are supposed to be js files, not json.

Comment: I wasn't able to get that to work unfortunately. I've added a few updates to my question.

Comment: It's unclear what it looks like at this moment. There should be no `jest` in package.json, only jest.config.js. There should be `setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/setup.js']` in jest.config.js, setup.js should be located outside tests because it's not a test. Make syntax mistake in setup.js on purpose to make sure it's loaded.